# Scenario Mapping from Sequence Diagrams

Tags: mapping, conditional-statements, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram, scenarios

I use Sequence Diagrams to show how flows of Use Case are implemented.

I would like lean on the Sequence diagram to map the possible scenarios to an Excel sheet.
I mean: according to the conditions in the sequence diagram flow I will have an ordered list of possible scenarios and output. Such as:

if condition `1`, `2` and `4` are met -> then the output is **A**
if only `2` and `4` are met -> then the output is **B**
if only condition `1` is met -> then the output is **C**
and so on...

Is there a built-in feature that performs this or something similar?
Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a custom feature to me. Maybe this could be achieved scripting your own extension ? It's not that hard really, it is well documented.

Comment: @ahesa, Thanks. I know the EA API is not hard, but what is the logical way to analyze the data on the Sequence diagram? any ideas?

Comment: I'm struggling to visualie what you're asking. Can you add an example sequence diagram so we can see what the input is?